# one setup file for java application and web application server installation?

Tags: java, web-applications, installation

I have a web application made with java that runs on Apache Tomcat. I need to give the application to for easy deployment for several clients.

For that I am required to create a installation file this case for windows, but hope it could be cross OS. This installation should be setup Tomcat and install my web application and mysql database with relevant settings.

Any resources I could use this for?

Comment: Just a question: who are your clients? If you have an application that targets the common user who can't/doesn't want to setup a web server and/or mysql instance, why is your application a web application in the first place? That said, requiring an experienced user to install a web-server (does it have to be Tomcat or would it be the user's choice?) and mysql doesn't seem that hard a requirement.

Comment: If the app is simple enough can't you zip up Tomcat+Application+Database and give that to your client?

Comment: @Thomas thanks for your reply. Within the client machine it servers the PC's inside their network.They had been experiencing some internet downtime in their area. So this allow them to work when internet is unavailable. when it's back it contact the central server and sync.

Comment: @PaulGrime Thanks for the response. Sadly client doesn't have any technical staff to carry it out. So I need to make it simple as possible like running a setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Advanced Installer](http://advancedinstaller.com/) has a project type just for Tomcat web applications. But it's a commercial tool so you will need a license. If you want a free solution, you can try [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/).